# Large binary file in jpa

Tags: jpa, ejb

I have ejb + JPA app on GF3 server and remote swing client. I want upload large files from client to server's database over stateless session bean.
how to upload large binary data from remote swing client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Entity Bean, you can use Blob field type & annotate it by @Lob to persist such data directly into database.

//-- Edit Part

For such a large file, you can fetch the file contents into byte array of fixed size such that client won't run out of memory.

Client side:

```
//-------------    

    remoteInterface.initializeArraySize(ARRAY_SIZE);

    double splitIterations = ARRAY_SIZE/PERMISSIBLE_SIZE;

    for(int i=0; i < splitIterations; i++){

    // Get next byte[PERMISSIBLE_SIZE] from File

        remoteInterface.appendToArray(splittedArray);
    }

    // Finally uploading after processing

        remoteInterface.uploadFile

//---------------
```

Server side:

```
    @Stateless
    public class FileUploadSessionBean implements FileUploadSessionBeanRemote {

    private byte[] byteArray;

    public void initializeArraySize(double arraySize){

         // Initilialized only once
         byteArray = new byteArray[arraySize];
    }

    public void appendToArray(byte[] splittedByteArray){

    /* Append the splittedByteArray at end to byteArray each time
       to build the original array
    */
    }

    public void uploadFile(){

      // Convert byteArray to Blob & persist
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but files are up to 2 GB and my client run out of memory exception. Is there some technique to get InputStream / OutputStream from app server using ejb?

Comment: thanks for reply. if this bean is will be accessed by five or more users with 2 GB files and servers memory is only 4 GB ? :)

Comment: Yes that was I am saying, split it according to your requirements like say for 2GB file - split into 400mb data & append successively on server calling it 5 times. Also you can delay little-bit execution after sending 400mb data so other users can consume server resources.

Comment: maybe it is solution, but in such case   @Stateless beans private variable byteArray can be accessed and changed by another app user. as I remember stateless instance variable are shared between bean invokers. am i right?

Comment: Yes, so to maintain conversational state, you can use a singleton helper class, & can have a global ConcurrentHashMap containing a custom clientId as a key with byteArray as value. At server side instead of using instance variable, fetch it directly from ConcurrentHashMap using particular client Id.

Comment: when clients upload file to ConcurrentHashMap and ConcurrentHashMaps data will grow, data will be allocated in servers RAM, or it will be temporary stored in temp file?

Comment: if remote swing client get DataSource and use connection to upload file directly to database will it right approach?

Comment: I can't lock DataSource lookup for unauthorized clients. do you know how to lock JNDI lookup for unauthorized clients?

Comment: You can limit number of entries in map. Also exposing datasource to client is not feasible approach. Instead you can try using FTP service. Open source API's are available for it like Apache FTP.

Comment: I started reading about Apache FTP, it is new to me I will try to understand :) it is possible to map user & password from my gf custom realm to Apache FTP server. Thanks !